# spring-batch-integration 1.2.2 not compatible with spring-batch 2.2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have an spring batch project which was working fine
old version:

- spring 3.1.2.RELEASE
- spring-batch 2.1.9.RELEASE
- spring-batch-integration 1.2.0.RELEASE

It stopped working when I upgraded version of all dependencies
new versions:

- spring 3.2.5.RELEASE
- spring-batch 2.2.2.RELEASE
- spring-batch-integration 1.2.2.RELEASE

Application log says:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExce ption: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceAct ivatorFactoryBean#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/retry/RetryException
```

The retry functionality was pulled out of Spring Batch as of 2.2.0. It is now part of a new library, Spring Retry.
but spring-batch-integration refers to older spring-batch and causing this error. class ChunkProcessorChunkHandler have import statement `import org.springframework.batch.retry.RetryException;`

I want to know how to overcome this error? and is there any plan for new version of spring-batch-integration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We currently have a milestone for 1.3.0 that is available and should work with the 2.2.x branch.  We're still working on timing for the 1.3.0 GA release.